# Efficient way to round to arbitrary precision in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

What is a Pythonic solution to the following?

I'm reading a temperature sensor that has .5 resolution. I need to write to it (it has a programmable thermostat output), also with .5 resolution.

So I wrote this function (Python 2.7) to round off a float as input to the to the nearest .5:

```
def point5res(number):
    decimals = number - int(number)
    roundnum = round(number, 0)
    return roundnum + .5 if .25 <= decimals < .75 else roundnum

print point5res (6.123)

print point5res(6.25)

print point5res(6.8)
```

Which works fine, outputs 6.0, 6.5 and 7.0, respectively. That's just what I want.

I'm relatively new to Python. The line

```
return roundnum + .5 if .25 <= decimals < .75 else roundnum
```

has me drooling with admiration for it implementors. But is it Pythonic?

Edit: since posting, I have learned a little more about [what is and isn't 'Pythonic'](http://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html). My code isn't. Cmd's anwwer, below, is. Thank you!

Comment: or negative values in general I suppose

Comment: Try 6.51. The result is 7.5. But you're right, chained comparisons are a great feature. And the ternary expression syntax, once you "get" it, is very nice, too.

Comment: That 6.51 result is interesting

Comment: Some may scoff at it not being as readable, but most C-family languages have this in the form of the ternary statement. For example, in JavaScript, Java, C#, serveral others: `return 0.25 <= decimals < 0.75 ? roundnum + 0.5 : roundnum;`

Comment: @dwerner: true they do have it, but `&&` is to `and` as `!` is to `not` as `||` is to `or` as `?:` is to `if else` as `ugly` is to `pretty` =P. i think part of the reason of the particular ordering (e.g. `1 ? 2 : 3` is equivalent to `2 if 1 else 3`) was to have nice short english words for the operator.

Comment: @Claudiu agreed and that's not to mention the power of expression chaining that is inherent in python. Since this seemed to me the main point of the post, I thought I'd make a note on it's expression in other languages.

Comment: I think the question should be re-titled: "Efficient way to round to arbitrary precision in Python" or something like that. It isn't really and x or y kind of problem.

Comment: @beroe Thanks for the hint. I had been wondering about that.  
Everyone, many thanks for the review. The thermostat function is that you set a desired temperature. In my case, that is the temperature humans desire in their house, i.e. never below zero. (More often between 15 and 21 or so.) But you're right, for a 'universal' application it would need revising.

Comment: I was hoping my post wouldn't be blocked for being 'opinion-based'. I was looking for (and got) expert review. I don't know any other platform where I can get that (and boy, have I searched!). If anyone does, please enlighten me. I don't like never-ending discussion either.

Comment: @RolfBly I'm afraid that a "Pythonic solution" roughly equates, however culturally infused, as an "Opinionated solution"...

Answer (score 8):

They are considered pythonic if you keep the expressions simple otherwise it becomes difficult to read.

I would round to the nearest 0.5 like this:

```
round(number*2) / 2.0
```

or more generically:

```
def roundres(num, res):
    return round(num / res) * res
```

Comment: Comparing to the OP's given examples, this doesn't return the same values. This is returning whole numbers (try for 6.25)

Comment: @CDspace the original one had issues which is why I posted an alternative.  Also compairing `==` on a float is not going to behave as expected.

Comment: Be aware that `round()` has changed its behavior between Python 2 and Python 3. `round(0.5)` is `1` in Python 2 and `0` in Python 3. So this solution only works in Python 2. Which is what the OP is using, so +1

Comment: @cmd I had tested with Python 3.3, which returned 6 when testing 6.25, my bad

Comment: +1. far more pythonic to do `round(number*2) / 2.0` instead of three lines of code

Comment: @RolfBly: For which input(s) does this Solution give wrong results, in your opinion?

Comment: @TimPietzcker You're right, there aren't any. I was thinking of `round(number*2)//2`, which I had been playing with but is of course different. 

@cmd Thanks a bunch! Your solution is much better than mine, more concise and works for negative numbers as well. So +1! I do think that 'difficult to read' depends on mathematical insight here. Some are more gifted than others, in that area.

Comment: @RolfBly 'difficult to read' is hard to quantify.  Best judgement should be used.  I do think even if a programmer is inexperienced seeing the python version of ternary operator causes little confusion.  However, if you find that your ternary statement is taking multiple lines (especially 3+), I'd argue that clarity is compromised for little to no gain over a normal `if-else` statement.  Also specifically in your original solution, a set of parens could clear up even a newbies confusion over the statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
return 0.5 * divmod (number, 0.5) [0] if number >= 0 else -0.5 divmod (number, -0.5) [0]
```

This looks nicer though:

```
def roundToHalf (number):
    ''' Round to nearest half '''
    half = 0.5 if number >= 0 else -0.5
    return half * divmod (number, half) [0]
```